# Paying attention: are we free to do so?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, attention

I got confused a bit after watching these two **short** videos: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBtRN0R3VV8), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OunyV_HgGBc) .

In first one it seems author suggests that: **we aren't in much control** on what to pay attention to? **Did I get it correctly? Or maybe I misunderstood?**

In the 2nd video, same author, seems to encourage to pay attention to things.
I find this somehow conflicting with first one.

Can someone help clarify this?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I don't think there can be more research done because I am referring to two specific videos which have been linked already, there is no point in any other research. if someone was able to answer, he/she should be able to do so already given the information in question. So I don't understand your problem, and maybe this sites approach is reason also why this site has least subject matter experts than other SE sites.

Comment: Watching *short videos* as you called them (#1 = 3 minutes and #2 = 1.5 minutes) is not prior research into a topic area of any science. You are bound to find something conflicting when trying to take a short piece of information into context. I suggest reading into "free will" and "unconscious decision making". No question is a stupid question but once you have some background information you can link to you can help the answerer take half an hour to answer a question with citations in their answer rather than half a day or more as they will need to find good and relevant reliable sources.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yes but in this case the answerer has to understand (better than OP) what the presenter in video *said*, and explain it maybe (if answerer understood it). Doing much prior work doesn't help in this case because we are dealing with contents in the video and what author said-- and maybe also how it related to other existing information on this topic. And since persons who ask questions aren't experts in psychology it can be hard  for them to do prior research in this case.